# CRON TAB gets not executed after reupload of target file

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I've set up a crontab which runs a python file every minute. It worked as long as I reuploaded the target python file again via FTP while the cronjob was running.

When I look into the syslog of cron it seems all correctly set up and is executed every minute as expected, but in logs of the python file there is no execution protocolled.

I already tried to change the path permissions with chmod and deleted the crontab and set it up again.

Do you have an idea why the python scripted is not exectued after the reupload via FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use absolute paths in the python script!